# LED drivers and Ontario Electrical Code

Tags: code-compliance, led, recessed-lighting

I'm doing a new build and I'm interested in using the inexpensive LED lights that use an external driver box.  My question is about code - what's the way to mount the driver so it's acceptable to an inspector?